# Moose class by extending

Tags: perl, moose

I want to create a class from WWW::Mechanize that consumes WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder role, and this works fine, if the main code sits in the same module file.

```
package My::Mechanize;
use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;

extends 'WWW::Mechanize';
with 'WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder' => {
    tree_class => 'HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath'
};

has json => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'JSON',
    default => sub { JSON->new; },
    lazy => 1,
    handles => [ qw(encode decode)]
);

no moose;
1;

# main code here works fine
```

Moving the main code to another script, i.e.,

```
use My::Mechanize;
```

Gives me a compilation error:

```
Can't use string ("My::Mechanize") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" 
in use at reader My::Mechanize::tree (defined at       
c:/Perl64/site/lib/WWW/Mechanize/TreeBuilder.pm line 167) line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at D:\scripts\pdf.pl line 2.
```

What am I doing wrong? And what is the fix for that? Many thanks.

I have also tried replacing Moose with MooseX::InsideOut. It died at the same spot with a different message (probably on the same problem)

```
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at reader My::Mechanize::tree   
(defined at c:/Perl64/site/lib/WWW/Mechanize/TreeBuilder.pm line 167) 
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at reader My::Mechanize::tree     
(defined at c:/Perl64/site/lib/WWW/Mechanize/TreeBuilder.pm line 167) 
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at reader My::Mechanize::tree    
(defined at c:/Perl64/site/lib/WWW/Mechanize/TreeBuilder.pm line 167)

Cannot delegate import to import because the value of tree is not defined at    
c:/Perl64/lib/Moose/Meta/Method/Delegation.pm line 99.

My::Mechanize::import("My::Mechanize") called at D:\scripts\pdf.pl line 1
main::BEGIN() called at D:\scripts\pdf.pl line 1
eval {...} called at D:\scripts\pdf.pl line 1
```

It looks like I need to initialize the "tree", which I have no clue how to :)

**WORKAROUND:** This seems to work for me

```
sub BUILD {
    WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder->meta->apply(shift, 
    tree_class =>  'HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath');
}
```

**SYMPTOMS**

- Extending using *"with"*

  - worked for code within the module file
  - FAILED at compile time when importing the module via "use"
- Extending using BUILD (run-time initialization of the role)

  - SUCCEEDED in allowing other scripts to import the module
  - disallows modification of the role methods since it is not yet in the inheritance hierarchy

**Technical Details**

- Activestate Perl 5.16.3 Win64
- Moose 2.1005
- WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder 1.1003

**FIX**

- Upgrade Moose to 2.1605
- Upgrade WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder to 1.20 via CPAN

Comment: Do you do anything specific in your main code that is relevant, or is it enough to `use` and instantiate a mech? I can run your code on my Ubuntu on 5.20.1 machine. I put My::Mechanize in its own file and did `use My::Mechanize; use Data::Printer; my $foo = My::Mechanize->new; p $foo;` without any errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Per your comment, I went to check on the various module versions. Upgrading Moose gave error: "load_class" is deprecated. Upgrading WWW::Mechanize::Treebuilder seems to quiet things down.  :-) Cheers.

Comment: You should post that as your own answer and accept it so there is a proper answer. :-)

Comment: Done. Thank you for the suggestion. I am new to this :-)

Answer (score 1):

**SYMPTOMS**

- Extending using *"with"*

  - worked for code within the module file
  - FAILED at compile time when importing the module via "use"
- Extending using BUILD (run-time initialization of the role)

  - SUCCEEDED in allowing other scripts to import the module
  - disallows modification of the role methods since it is not yet in the inheritance hierarchy

**Observed In**

- Activestate Perl 5.16.3 Win64
- Moose 2.1005
- WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder 1.1003

**FIX**

- Upgrade Moose to 2.1605
- Upgrade WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder to 1.20 via CPAN